# Why are my optional interface properties incorrectly inferred after a type guard?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have an Interface with an optional field `foo` and a function that takes a generic object as a parameter.

I want to do something with `foo` if the passed object matches my interface, but TypeScript isn't inferring `foo`'s type properly.

Why isn't TypeScript able to infer `foo`'s type?
Is there anything I can do to help it along?

**Code:**

```js
interface SpecificThing {
  foo?: number;
}

const isSpecificThing = (item: unknown): item is SpecificThing => true // the guard doesn't matter

function example(thing: Record<string, unknown>): number {
  if (isSpecificThing(thing)) {
    return thing.foo ?? 0; // This line is flagged as "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'."
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Things that "fix" it:**

Any one of the following changes to the above example would satisfy TypeScript:

1. If I modify my function signature so that `thing` is `Record<string, number>`
2. If I modify my function signature so that `thing` is `unknown`.
3. If I modify the `SpecificThing` interface to be `foo: number | undefined`.
4. If I add any non-optional attribute to `SpecificThing`.
5. Updating the type guard to inline the type (e.g. `item is {foo?:number}`). (h/t to `@vr.`)

That said, none of these solutions is ideal for my case.  Is there a way to keep my interface definition and function signature while still being able to utilize `foo`?

Comment: `number | unknown` is really just `unknown`

Comment: Oh and what's even more interesting is that changing the type predicate to an inlined-version of `SpecificThing` works... https://tsplay.dev/N75pqW

Comment: re `number | unknown` good call, that was a typo in my list of solutions -- fixing now (should be `number | undefined`) -- interestingly, `number | unknown` in the type maintains the issue!

Comment: A more explicit guard would use a generic for the parameter and intersect the generic with the asserted type in the predicate ([example](https://tsplay.dev/mMX5lN)). If that addresses your question, I can write it up as an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Another way is to extend `SpecificThing` such as `interface SpecificThing extends Record<string, unknown>`, I guess it's in the same direction as having `item is {foo?:number}` in the guard.

Comment: Also, changing to `type SpecificThing =` works, somehow TS has a hard time aligning the interface with conditional props and Record<string, unknown>.

Comment: @jsejcksn I think `item is T & SpecificThing` in the generic guard converts it effectively to `type`. Say, `SpecificThing & true` also works.

Answer (score 0):

You could assure typescript that you know better about the type like

```
function example(thing: Record<string, unknown>): number {
  if (isSpecificThing(thing)) {
    return (thing as SpecificThing).foo ?? 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Assertion can solve it, it's generally not a good practice to use type assertions.

So to fix this provide TypeScript with more information about the shape of the `thing` object. To do this define a type that extends Record<string, unknown> and includes the properties of `SpecificThing` that you want like optional `foo`:

```
interface SpecificThingFoo {
  foo?: number;
}

type SpecificThing = Record<string, unknown> & SpecificThingFoo;
```

example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAcIODYCAqAFqAOYCSICANgK4AmEAzgGID2ryA3gLABQyyGOwD8ALmQgaAWwBG0ANx8Avnz5gAnpjSZsuAsRAlkAXmQAlLKyh0APIzBRSAGmQ0QAaxCsA7iAB8yABk2lg4eESkFNT0TGysirx8CKwg9sjAjBihehGGJsgAFMCQUuJunj4gAJTixRBS6YwhuuEGRsYBDjQoAPQ9yGCEKCQ0cNbIdKxMIADkYMhScGCQUKq8MG4IYMApyBAAHnBS6FQQBYOk4hbJ1nYOzq4eXr5%20NRLSclBcfAI4hRlZFr6UjnNpVKrffgCZBQCBgGhQEADNoAOiEHGEwmQAAYEgIVFDYfDETiEkogA)

Above you define a new type `SpecificThing` that extends `Record<string, unknown>` and includes the `foo` property from interface `SpecificThingFoo`. The guard rests unchanged.

Now, when you try to access the `foo` property inside the if block, TypeScript correctly infers its type as `number | undefined`, and you can safely use the `??` operator to provide a default value.